# to call a jquery function present in another page

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Consider two pages one is hello.html and another is wow.html.

**hello.html** consists of fallowing script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#loader" ).load( "wow.html");
});
</script>
```

and in **wow.html** consists of following jquery function

```
$(function () {
  $('.bysh').on('submit', function (e) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'entco.jsp',
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function (result) {
      }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Now how call document.ready function present in hello.html on ajax form submission success in wow.html .
And any one please tell me how to reload/refresh a page without reloading effect.

Comment: write content of hello.html in function and call that function in success of ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

in hello.html:

```
function initFunc() {
    $("#loader").load("wow.html");
}
$(document).ready(initFunc);
```

now in wow.html you are able to call `initFunc()` whenever you need to.

hope that helps.